# Sqoop and MSSQL with window auth on linux fails

Tags: sql-server, linux, apache, sqoop

I m using apache sqoop to connect mSSQL server using window authentication but
I am not able to login when I run:

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.xx.xx:1433;username=xxxxx;password=xxxxxx;database=xxxxx;
```

I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'username'. ClientConnectionId:a593dc10-2d06-4b8b-b53b-e743fb133d0e
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:73)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ListDatabasesTool.run(ListDatabasesTool.java:49)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'username'. ClientConnectionId:a593dc10-2d06-4b8b-b53b-e743fb133d0e
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2908)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2234)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2220)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1326)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:824)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.CatalogQueryManager.listDatabases(CatalogQueryManager.java:57)
        ... 7 more
```

Comment: you could try adding property 'integratedSecurity=false' into your jdbc connection string. Also windows authentication does not guarantee existing of a such user on database site

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to say but the current answer is that Sqoop does not support integrated authentication (Kerberos) for any databases.

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/20719/sqoop-to-sql-server-with-integrated-security.html#answer-82516

I spent months on this and was told by Cloudera that it is just not possible. The kerberos tokens are lost when the mappers spawn (as the YARN transitions the job to its internal security subsystem).

I think this is something that would have to be added to Sqoop itself, much like HBase mapreduce jobs have to pass job config to mappers in the code Sqoop able to do the same.

I spent weeks trying different things, doing network traces (all my servers are tied to AD with Centrify, ext), watched the token drop, and finally found a paper written by Yahoo about YARN that explains the internal token subsystem it uses (after using Kerberos to externally verify someone it moves to different token based subsystem for performance).

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from a Linux machine you and you want to leverage direct auth you need to do a few things.

First, your Linux system needs to be integrated with Active Directory via Kerberos (tons of articles on this).

Second, you need to change your connection string:
dbc:sqlserver://;serverName=$fqdnOfDatabaseHost;database=$databaseName;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos"

Replacing the $variables with the ones for your environment.

There is more information on this here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2015/01/09/jdbc-this-driver-is-not-configured-for-integrated-authentication.aspx

Using Kerberos Integrated Authentication to Connect to SQL Server
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122(v=sql.110).aspx

As a secondary option, if you do not feel like going through the hassle of integrating Linux to AD via Kerberos there are 3rd party paid for drivers you can purchase that will allow you to avoid this.

Data direct provides one, I cannot link since I don't have enough rep (created account to reply to this).

Answer (score 0):

Use "integratedSecurity=true" for windows authetication instead of username and password.

Your sqoop statement should look like below

`sqoop list-databases --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.xx.xx:1433;integratedSecurity=true;database=xxxxx;'`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below to use jtds for sqoop sql and windows authentication:

1) Download the jtds driver from: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/ (find the FAQ on jtds at http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) 
2) Copy jtds files to sqoop lib 
3) Use the following connection string template to modify according to your environment and connect: 
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://db_server:1433/DB_NAME;domain=NT_DOMAIN_NAME;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this provided by another user here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/20719/sqoop-to-sql-server-with-integrated-security.html

Basically if you switch to the jtds driver which you can download here: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Per Rajendra Manjunath

"

Sqoop SQL Server data import to HDFS worked with manual parametric the authentication(using windows credential) with added parameter on the SQL Server JDBC driver, as integrated security is not supported by the SQL driver as of now due to the Kerberos authentication(Delegated tokens distributed over cluster while running MR job).

So we need to pass the windows authentication with password and with the integrated security disabled mode to import the data to the system. As normal SQL server driver does not support, so I had used the jtds.jar and the different driver class to pull the data to the Hadoop Lake.

Sample Command I tried on the server as follows,

sqoop import --table Table1 --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://:;useNTLMv2=true;domain=;databaseName=XXXXXXXXXXXXX" \

--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --username XXXXX --password 'XXXXXXX' \

--verbose --target-dir /tmp/33 -m 1 -- --schema dbo

"

Here are some examples that worked for me:

## List databases

sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://databasehostname.yourdomain.com:1433;useNTLMv2=true;domain=myactivedirectorydomain.com" --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --username XXXXX -P

## List tables

sqoop list-tables --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://databasehostname.yourdomain.com:1433;useNTLMv2=true;domain=myactivedirectorydomain.com;databaseName=DATABASENAMEHERE" --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --username jmiller.admin -P

## Pull data example

sqoop import --table TABLENAMEHERE --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://databasehostname.yourdomain.com:1433;useNTLMv2=true;domain=myactivedirectorydomain.com;databaseName=DATABASENAMEHERE" --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --username XXXXX -P --fields-terminated-by '\001' --target-dir /user/XXXXX/20170313 -m 1 -- --schema dbo

Note* In the above example you need to change the username to your username and database name in the list-tables or pull to the one you need (note the AD account you use will require access to the data).

Answer (score 0):

Integrated authentication does not work with MS SQLServer JDBC driver in a secure cluster with AD integration as the containers will not have the context as the Kerberos tokens are lost when the mappers spawn (as the YARN transitions the job to its internal security subsystem).

Here is my repo that was used as work around to get Kerberos/AD authentication
https://github.com/chandanbalu/mssql-jdbc-krb5, solution implements a Driver that overrides connect method of the latest MS SQL JDBC Driver (mssql-jdbc-9.2.1.jre8.jar), and will get a ticket for keytab file/principal, and gives this connection back.

You can grab the latest build of this custom driver from release folder [here](https://github.com/chandanbalu/mssql-jdbc-krb5/tree/main/release)

**Sqoop** command

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/efs/home/c795701/mssql-jdbc-krb5/target/scala-2.10/mssql-jdbc-krb5_2.10-1.0.jar:/efs/home/c795701/.ivy2/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar

sqoop import -libjars "/efs/home/c795701/mssql-jdbc-krb5/target/scala-2.10/mssql-jdbc-krb5_2.10-1.0.jar,/efs/home/c795701/.ivy2/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar" \
-files "/efs/home/c795701/c795701.keytab" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager \
--driver hadoop.sqlserver.jdbc.krb5.SQLServerDriver \
--connect "jdbc:krb5ss://<SERVER_NAME>:1433;databasename=<DATABASE_NAME>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;krb5Principal=c795701@NA.DOMAIN.COM;krb5Keytab=/efs/home/c795701/c795701.keytab" \
--query "SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE \$CONDITIONS" \
--delete-target-dir \
--target-dir "/dev/product/sandbox/<table_name>" \
--num-mappers 1 \
--verbose \
-- --schema "dbo"
```

Comment: It looks like you've included a link to your own project, or a project that you're affiliated with. If this is the case, [you *must* disclose your affiliation in the answer itself](/help/promotion). Without this disclosure, your post could be considered spam.

Comment: Thanks! I think it's perfectly reasonable to state the affiliation. I'll will include in my answers going forward if the answer needs the link to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some Sqoop commands using jTDS to access and import the data from Microsoft SQL Server using windows authentication.

First download jtds driver and place it in your local then export it.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:<path>jtds-1.3.1.jar

sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;database=<db_name>;domain=<domain>;useNTLMv2=true" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager \
--driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver \
--username <user_name> --password-alias \
--query "SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE \$CONDITIONS" -m 1\
--target-dir "<HDFS_PATH>" \
```

Answer (score -1):

For Windows Authentication and importing directly into Hive this worked for me:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/apps/lib/java/jdbc/jtds-1.3.1-patched/jtds-1.3.1.jar \
sqoop import --table XXXXX --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://XXXX:1433;useNTLMv2=true;domain=XXXX;databaseName=XXXXXX" \
--split-by XXXXX --num-mappers 10 --hive-import --hive-table test --hive-overwrite \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager --driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --username XXXX -P \
--verbose --target-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/XXXX/XXX-$(uuidgen) \
-- --schema XXXXX
```